# Method Not Found when using LightInject with MVC5 and .Net 4.5

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, light-inject

When setting up LightInject for an MVC controller I am getting an error when calling `container.EnableMvc();` in the injector setup.

Error:

> Method not found:
>   'Void LightInject.WebContainerExtensions.EnablePerWebRequestScope(LightInject.IServiceContainer)'

Source:

```
public static void Register() {
    var container = new ServiceContainer();
    container.ScopeManagerProvider = new PerLogicalCallContextScopeManagerProvider();
    WebContainerExtensions.EnablePerWebRequestScope(container);
    container.RegisterControllers();

    container.Register<ISomeClass, SomeClass>();

    container.EnableMvc();
}
```

Additional Information:

- I am running the code locally through Visual Studio
- The project is 4.5
- My OS is Windows 10 (framework 4.5)

In the past when I have setup LightInject I have set the scope lifetime manually but the documentation, for general setup and MVC specific examples, has since changed. I came across one thread that mentioned this could be an issue with not including LightInject.Web as a dep, but I can see it listed as a dep for LightInject.MVC and in the list of references in the project.

Are there any other steps I can take to manually configure the lifetime or otherwise verify that this method is available before Enabling MVC?

Comment: Does this help... https://github.com/seesharper/LightInject/issues/170 ?

Comment: I added that to the code but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here was that I installed LightInject.MVC with NuGet. It lists it's dependencies as:

> LightInject.Web (>= 1.0.0.4)
>   LightInject (>= 3.0.1.7)

The after I exhausted this being an issue with versions of .Net 4.5 and possible issues with async. I decided to manually update both `LightInject.Web` and `LightInject` to their newest versions. After the update it resolved the issue.

I will add this as a bug in the listed dependencies on the projects site.